# Load balancing with socket.io server with nginx using redis

Tags: node.js, nginx, redis, socket.io, load-balancing

I am working on a chat project using **Typescript**, **Node.js**, **Socket.io** and **React** frontend.
My application is working fine for a single server instance. But while load balancing with multiple servers the chat feature is not working. I used Redis and @socket.io/redis-adapter to solve the issue. But its still not working. Where am I doing wrong?

This is my nginx conf

```
upstream backend {
      server 127.0.0.1:8000; 
      server 127.0.0.1:8001;
   }

   server {
      listen 80; 

      location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://backend;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      }
    }
```

This is my socket.io implementation in server.js

```
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents>(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? process.env.ALLOWED_HOST: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  },
  transports: ['websocket']
});

// redis config


const pubClient = createClient({ url: 'redis://localhost:6379'});
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

Promise.all([pubClient.connect(), subClient.connect()]).then(() => {
  io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));
});


// routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to Node.js Server.  Server running on port 8000.");
});

app.use("/api/v1", apiRoutes);

// ********** Socket Start *********** //

// array of objects that stores online users
let users: { socketId: string; userId: string; username: string }[] = [];

// method for adding new user into users array
const addUser = (userId: string, socketId: string, username: string) => {
  if (
      userId &&
      !users.some((user) => user.socketId === socketId && user.userId === userId)
  ) {
    if (users.some((user) => user.socketId === socketId)) {
      users = users.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
    }
    users.push({ userId, socketId, username });
  }
};

// method for removing disconnected user from users array
const removeUser = (socketId: string) => {
  users = users.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
};

// method for getting user from users array
const getReceiver = (
    receiverId: string,
    senderId: string,
    socketId: string
) => {
  return users.filter(
      (user) =>
          user.userId === receiverId ||
          (user.userId === senderId && user.socketId !== socketId)
  );
};

// starting socket connection
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // establishing connection with client
  console.log(`a client connected on websocket.SocketId:${socket.id}`);

 //taking userId and username from client and pushing to users array along with socket id
  socket.on("addUser", ({ userId, username }) => {
    addUser(userId, socket.id, username);
    io.emit(SocketEvents.GET_USERS, users);  // sending online users to client side
  });

  //receiving message from sender and sending to the receiver
  socket.on("sendMessage", (message, receiverId) => {
    const user = getReceiver(receiverId, message.senderId, socket.id);
    if (user.length > 0) {
      user.forEach((u) => {
        io.to(u.socketId).emit("receiveMessage", message);
        socket.broadcast.emit('test' , {username: 'test'});
      });
    } else {
      io.to(socket.id).emit("error", "message not sent. receiver is offline");
    }
  });


  // disconnection of a client
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`a client disconnected from websocket.SocketId:${socket.id}`);
    removeUser(socket.id);
  });
});

// 404 not found handler
app.use(notFoundHandler);

// common error handler
app.use(errorHandler);

// ********** Socket End *********** //

server.listen(port,
    () => console.log(` Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io requires sticky sessions, not sure if the free version of nginx supports it.
Another options is to disable the HTTP long polling transport, from Socket.io docs:

> if you disable the HTTP long-polling transport (which is a perfectly valid choice in 2021), you won't need sticky sessions:

You can disable it like this:

```
io("https://example.com", {
  transports: ["websocket"]
});
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I solved it. The problem was the "users" array. I put the users array into redis and it solved the problem.